# How to close custom jquery drop down using like default select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to close a custom jquery drop down on click of outside of dropdown, just like default behavior of  HTML select dropdown, I tried  to use the window click but that is creating trouble in opening the dropdown it self.

```js
$(".selected").click(function() {
  $(".custom-dropdown-list").toggleClass("open");
});

$(".custom-dropdown-list li").click(function() {
  var dataVal = $(this).attr("data-val");
  var dpText1 = $(this).children('.dp-val1').text();
  var dpText2 = $(this).children('.dp-val2').text();
  $(".selected").attr("data-val", dataVal);
  $(".selected .dp-val1").text(dpText1);
  $(".selected .dp-val2").text(dpText2);
  $(".custom-dropdown-list").removeClass("open");
});
```

```css
.custom-dropdown {
  width: 300px;
}

.selected {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-height: 37px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.custom-dropdown-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}

.custom-dropdown-list.open {
  display: block;
}

.custom-dropdown-list li {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-dropdown-list li:hover {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-dropdown">
  <div class="selected" data-val="">
    <div class="dp-val1">
      Selected Bank</div>
    <div class="dp-val2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="custom-dropdown-list">
    <li data-val="0">
      <div class="dp-val1">Option Dp0</div>
      <div class="dp-val2">5879464954426 (LKP)</div>
    </li>
    <li data-val="1">
      <div class="dp-val1">Option Dp1</div>
      <div class="dp-val2">5879464954426 (LKP)</div>
    </li>
    <li data-val="2">
      <div class="dp-val1">Option Dp2</div>
      <div class="dp-val2">5879464954426 (LKP)</div>
    </li>
    <li data-val="3">
      <div class="dp-val1">Option Dp3</div>
      <div class="dp-val2">5879464954426 (LKP)</div>
    </li>
    <li data-val="4">
      <div class="dp-val1">Option Dp4</div>
      <div class="dp-val2">5879464954426 (LKP)</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JSfiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/5zgyouwL/1/

Comment: You can collect all the below answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This will work fine for you:**

In this method I have used [**`event.stopPropagation();`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Your method was right on the path, it just needed some tweaks - I have  used the `click` on the `<html>` to but the difference is that I have prevented the body click on the `.selected` and `.custom-dropdown-list li` using `event.stopPropagation();`.

```js
$("html").click(function(event) {
  $(".custom-dropdown-list").removeClass("open");
});

$(".selected").click(function() {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(".custom-dropdown-list").toggleClass("open");
});


$(".custom-dropdown-list li").click(function() {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var dataVal = $(this).attr("data-val");
  var dpText1 = $(this).children('.dp-val1').text();
  var dpText2 = $(this).children('.dp-val2').text();
  $(".selected").attr("data-val", dataVal);
  $(".selected .dp-val1").text(dpText1);
  $(".selected .dp-val2").text(dpText2);
  $(".custom-dropdown-list").removeClass("open");
});
```

```css
.custom-dropdown {
  width: 300px;
}

.selected {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-height: 37px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.custom-dropdown-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}

.custom-dropdown-list.open {
  display: block;
}

.custom-dropdown-list li {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-dropdown-list li:hover {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-dropdown">
  <div class="selected" data-val="">
    <div class="dp-val1">
      Selected Bank</div>
    <div class="dp-val2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="custom-dropdown-list">
    <li data-val="0">
      <div class="dp-val1">Option Dp0</div>
      <div class="dp-val2">5879464954466 (LKP)</div>
    </li>
    <li data-val="1">
      <div class="dp-val1">Option Dp1</div>
      <div class="dp-val2">5879464954466 (LKP)</div>
    </li>
    <li data-val="2">
      <div class="dp-val1">Option Dp2</div>
      <div class="dp-val2">5879464954466 (LKP)</div>
    </li>
    <li data-val="3">
      <div class="dp-val1">Option Dp3</div>
      <div class="dp-val2">5879464954466 (LKP)</div>
    </li>
    <li data-val="4">
      <div class="dp-val1">Option Dp4</div>
      <div class="dp-val2">5879464954466 (LKP)</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this was helpfull.

Comment: What if body is not covering the window height? Will it still work? Try your demo with full screen.

Comment: @divy3993 It will work in all height, as long as you are clicking on your page's body.

Comment: Yeah, you need body to be same as window height to work, for it to work. But that might not be the case all time

Comment: @divy3993 sorry, I don't get you, In every case, if you are using a `<body>` tag in your page the height of the window or document should be same as the body. In HTML every component should come underbody, so this will work fine.

Comment: @DragonBorn ok, Now I get it. It's in the fiddle right. because the body is not `100%` as the fiddle page. But this will work well in real life scenario guys. But i will fix it for you guyz.

Comment: @divy3993 I fixed it using a simple fix - by adding `html` with the `body` ty for the heads up bro. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think what you might want is when clicked anywhere else of custom select/dropdown it must close.

So here it is:

```js
$(".selected").click(function(){
  $(".custom-dropdown-list").toggleClass("open");
});

$(".custom-dropdown-list li").click(function(){
    var dataVal = $(this).attr("data-val");
    var dpText1 = $(this).children('.dp-val1').text();
    var dpText2 = $(this).children('.dp-val2').text();    
    $(".selected").attr("data-val", dataVal);
    $(".selected .dp-val1").text(dpText1);
    $(".selected .dp-val2").text(dpText2);
  $(".custom-dropdown-list").removeClass("open");  
});

/*Mouse click anywhere but custom select dropdown, will close it. */
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
 var container = $(".custom-dropdown");
 if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $(".custom-dropdown-list").removeClass("open");
    }
});
```

```css
.custom-dropdown { width:300px;}
.selected { padding:5px; cursor:pointer; min-height:37px; background-color:#ccc;}
.custom-dropdown-list { list-style:none; padding:0; margin:0; display:none;}
.custom-dropdown-list.open {  display:block;}
.custom-dropdown-list li { padding:5px; cursor:pointer;}
.custom-dropdown-list li:hover { background:#f2f2f2;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-dropdown">
<div class="selected" data-val="">
<div class="dp-val1">
Selected Bank</div>
<div class="dp-val2">
</div>
</div>
<ul class="custom-dropdown-list">
<li data-val="0">
<div class="dp-val1">Option Dp0</div>
<div class="dp-val2">5879464954466 (LKP)</div>
</li>
<li data-val="1">
<div class="dp-val1">Option Dp1</div>
<div class="dp-val2">5879464954466 (LKP)</div>
</li>
<li data-val="2">
<div class="dp-val1">Option Dp2</div>
<div class="dp-val2">5879464954466 (LKP)</div> 
</li>
<li data-val="3">
<div class="dp-val1">Option Dp3</div>
<div class="dp-val2">5879464954466 (LKP)</div>
</li>
<li data-val="4">
<div class="dp-val1">Option Dp4</div>
<div class="dp-val2">5879464954466 (LKP)</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You wouldn't want to open the dropdown when clicked anywhere on the screen.

Comment: Thanks, Corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

The key is [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```
$('body').on('click', function(){
    // close the drop down
});

$('.custom-dropdown').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();    
});
```

Comment: Clean answer to show the main point. To close the drop down: `$(".custom-dropdown-list").removeClass("open");`

Answer (score 0):

You use Mouse Up Event Also  Like this

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) 
{
    var container = $(".custom-dropdown");

    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe @weBer answered your question , but another way to do this is to have an event handler right on your `html` element and inside that check if the targeted element or its children are being clicked :

```
$('html').on('click' , function(e){
   if($(e.target).closest('.custom-dropdown').length ) return 
   $(".custom-dropdown-list").toggleClass("open");
});
```

[**FIDDLE HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/5zgyouwL/10/)